# Proof of sum of cubes of odd numbers by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove by mathematical induction $$1^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + (2n - 1)^3 = n^2(2n^2-1),\forall n\geq1$$

Please help me solve this question using the mathematical induction method.

Comment: Do you know how induction work?

Comment: Help you? Or do all of it for you?  Sure I'll help you.  You do the first step and ask me a question.  Then I'll step in and help you.

Comment: Hint:  Can you prove that $n^2(2n-1) +(2n+1)^3 = (n+1)^2(2n+1)$?